# 'Workbook' object has no attribute 'write'

Tags: python, pandas, excel, dataframe

I plan to save the average data of the same month (a separate sheet in the Excel file for each month) in the last sheet and in the row corresponding to the average data after each time the following function is called.

for example:
In the first column and the second line of each month (each sheet), "shipping cost" is written, and the average for the whole year is 340 dollars. The code should store this value in the first column and second row of the last sheet.
The function I wrote is as follows:

```
def mean_cal(year_num):
    file = f'year_data/year-{year_num}.xlsx'
    dataframe = pd.read_excel(f'year_data/year-{year_num}.xlsx',
                              sheet_name=['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', 'total'])
    
    month = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12']
    categor = ['incomes', 'costs']
    info = []
    total = 0
    exl = xw.Workbook(file)
    for categ in categor:
        for row in range(0, 19):
            for month_check in month:
                try:
                    info.append(dataframe[month_check][categ][row])
                except ValueError or KeyError:
                    continue

            for collector in info:
                total += collector

            if categ == 'incomes':
                exl.write(f'F{row}', (total / (len(info))))
            else:
                pass
```

But the error it gives:

````
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Mahdi\Programming\Projects\Rabin amc\proj_func.py", line 209, in <module>
    mean_cal(1402)
  File "D:\Mahdi\Programming\Projects\Rabin amc\proj_func.py", line 106, in mean_cal
    exl.write(f'F{row}', (total / (len(info))))
    ^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'Workbook' object has no attribute 'write'```
````

Comment: I assume `xw` in your code is an alias for an imported module. However which module exactly is it?

Comment: import xlsxwriter as xw

Answer (score 1):

Your variable `exl` is assigned to a `Workbook` object. However as the error message says, this type of object doesn't have a `write()` attribute.

Before you can write values to cells, you have to create a [`Worksheet`](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/worksheet.html) object. This object does have a [`write()`](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/worksheet.html#write) attribute.

Simple usage example copied from the xlsxwriter documentation:

```
workbook   = xlsxwriter.Workbook('filename.xlsx')

worksheet1 = workbook.add_worksheet()
worksheet2 = workbook.add_worksheet()

worksheet1.write('A1', 123)

workbook.close()
```

It's worth noting that as an alternative to providing the cell address as a string you can also provide it as a row index integer and a column index integer. Example copied once again from the xlsxwriter documentation:

```
# These are equivalent.
worksheet.write(0, 0, 'Hello')
worksheet.write('A1', 'Hello')
```